# Will BLE peripheral role support be added to Android API in a future version?

Tags: android, ios6, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Apple did not initially include peripheral role support in iOS5, but then did in iOS6. Peripheral role support in Android would also be useful. Any insight on this topic would be helpful.

-Vik

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you've got to wait at least until 2014 Q4 to get a somewhat working peripheral role feature on a device that fully supports that feature. And even if you have that feature available, you have to wait another 6 to 12 months until major devices from major manufacturers support it.

But this role will come later as told by google engineers at https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326240948